# How can I connect any USB device to my computer wirelessly?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

I am trying to connect the Canon 550D wirelessly to my computer so that I can control it from at a distance. It can connect normally via a USB cable, so I was wondering if there was a way to plug a dongle into the computer, and a dongle into the camera so the two can connect. I'm basically looking for a really long USB cord that will work over long distances (200+ feet). Another important factor is that I really would prefer not having use a power cord, rather just plugging in a dongle, as it will make the setup more mobile. Does anything like this exist?

(I know that Cables Unlimited *had* [something like what I wanted](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036VNZHA), but they [went out of business last year](http://www.insideview.com/directory/cables-unlimited))

Comment: Be aware that even the unit you wanted had an external power supply that has a power cord. (The power supply isn't in the photos, but read the description carefully.)  The remote end needs electrical power for both powering the USB device and for the wireless transceiver.  Batteries probably would not last very long, so an AC-DC adapter is simply more practical.

Comment: @sawdust Note I said "*something* like what I wanted".

Answer (score 3):

There *are* be solutions out there, but from what I have seen, they get really poor reviews.  The problems seems to stem from the fact that that USB data streams do not transfer well to wireless signals.  The stream is just not designed to handle loss of signal.

A lot of people dont know there is wireless USB [Standard](http://www.usb.org/developers/wusb/).  However, it never caught on.  I havent seen a single wireless USB product on the market.  Plus, it doesnt have the distance you want.

The distance is another factor.  200+ feet is a long way.  I dont know if any solution out there would be able to transfer data reliably at that distance.

Comment: I did see the WUSB Standard. However, just like you said, there aren't really products out there. :-(

Answer (score 2):

The solution might be something very different: WiFi enabled memory card.

Before you laugh me off, it actually does exist.

Here's one review with two SDHC WiFi candidates, Google will find you more.
http://www.dpreview.com/articles/3140600438/battle-of-the-wi-fi-cards-eye-fi-vs-transcend

Answer (score 1):

Made some search, such devices are called as wusb(wireless usb) device. Belkin's network usb hub seems to be what you are looking for.

[http://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F5L009-5-Port-Network-USB/dp/B000QSN3O6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QSN3O6)
http://www.belkin.com/networkusbhub/

Seems this kind of usb hub not popular in market.

Comment: Thanks! This isn't exactly what I wanted though...I really need something more portable. Specifically, I need something that doesn't require a power cord. I'll add that to my question as well.

Comment: @daviesgeek Then you have a imposable requirement. The usb standard guarantees that the cable will provide [5V±5%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Power). Also it must be able to provide current of at least 100mA and up to 500mA. Batteries are not going to be able to provide that for any large length of time unless they are very large.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh...I guess I hadn't thought of that...

Answer (score 0):

A battery solution is really not that far fetched.  Lets say you picked up a Lithium 9.6 or 7.2 volt battery pack ( [Battery pack](http://www.megabatteries.com/cat_featured_items.asp?cat1=17&cat=2&id=154&uid=1311) ), a 7805 LDO regulator.  You could potentially easily be looking at 5 or 6 hours at a 500ma draw.

Answer (score -1):

A very cheap Win8 tablet + Remote Access.